# local shutdown scripts (do's and don't's)

Tags: environment-variables, init-script, services, vagrant, rc

At work, I'm running linux, and use vagrant on a daily basis. What I find annoying is that the system often hangs when I reboot/shut down, if I forgot to `vagrant halt` any virtual boxes I may have fired up.
To counter this, I'd like to write a shutdown script, along the lines of:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd ~/vagrants/vagrant_1
vagrant halt
cd ../vagrant_2
vagrant halt
exit 0
```

However, for I'm not too sure if `~` will still be available to me, and even if it is, if the *home* dir in question will always be the right one, and if the script will have access too it. So I thought I'd do:

```
#! /bin/sh
VAGRANT_HOME="~/vagrants/"    #or "/home/my_user/vagrants"
if [ -d "$VAGRANT_HOME" ]; then
    cd $VAGRANT_HOMEvagrant_1
    vagrant halt
    cd $VAGRANT_HOMEvagrant_2
    vagrant halt
fi
```

But even so, I can't help finding this silly, since I have added a couple of aliasses to my `.profile` file, including:

```
alias vagranthalt="cd ~/vagrants/vagrant_1 && vagrant halt && cd - && cd ~/vagrants/vagrant_2 && vagrant halt && cd -"
```

Which I'd like to use, but I'm not sure if these aliasses will still be available when my script is executed. I think I'll only need it @ runlevel 6, but might also need to symlink the script to run on runlevel 0, too.

Basically, what I'd like to know is this:

- will existing aliasses be available to me, or not?
- Is there a *user* executing this script (and will I therefore be able to use `~` for home?
- should I make sure I have, at least, read-rights on the vagrant dirs in the script
- Is there another way to ensure the vagrant boxes are shutdown, that is perhaps slightly easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't do something special vagrant is a wrapping for virtualbox.

You can get a list of running virtualboxes:

```
vboxmanage list runningvms
```

and parse the output to get a vmname, then do:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vmname> acpipowerbutton
```

Have to do this as the user that started the VMs

Put a link to the script in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` just like other softwares do ( `ls /etc/rc0.d /etc/rc6.d` ).

My script:

```
# coding: utf-8

import os
import pwd
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

user_name = 'zelda'


def main():
    os.chdir('/')
    cmd = ["vboxmanage", "list", "runningvms"]
    if os.getuid() == 0:
        cmd = ['su', '-l', user_name, ] + cmd
    try:
        res = check_output(cmd)
    except CalledProcessError:
        return
    for line in res.splitlines():
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        # split on first char
        vmname = line[1:].split(line[0])[0]
        cmd = ["VBoxManage", "controlvm", vmname, "acpipowerbutton"]
        if os.getuid() == 0:
            cmd = ['su', '-l', user_name, ] + cmd
        check_output(cmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I know, what I want to do is have a reboot/shudown script that automatically shuts down the VM's in case I forget. I'd just like to know how to best go about this, and what the environment in which these scripts run looks like

Comment: I have linked this in runlevel 0 *and* 6, look at the other software, they all do. Do you need the actual script?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me :), I'll give it a go, let you know if it worked

Comment: Right, upvoted your answer, as I've managed to put together a little script that _should_ do the job. I guess, I'll know by the end of today (when I can stop working). I'll leave this answer unchecked for the time being, hope you don't mind. But I've found that giving others more time to answer, can be useful